# Easiest way to build dynamic web application with data from DynamoDB on AWS Cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am developing the application where "form" plays an important role. I use the "form" for data collection from the users which I store it on DynamoDB and then these data should be displayed in my application synchronously or immediately after some trigger functions when the data has been inserted into the dynamoDB.

What is the best way to achieve this? How should I frame my infrastructure on the AWS Cloud? What are the services should I rely on?

Answer (score 0):

For "realtime" applications you should use something like graphQL.
On AWS you can use: AWS App Sync
https://console.aws.amazon.com/appsync/home?region=us-east-1#/

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this. However, one of most modernized way of building your applications today is using a Serverless Architecture. You can host your website on S3 and can go serverless with sample architecture as below

[image: ServerLess Application Architecture] (Note: you can just replace the Amazon Aurora with Dynamo DB in the architecture reference)

You can create a server less application on AWS using following AWS services:

1. AWS Lambda: AWS Lambda is a compute service that lets you run code without provisioning or managing servers.
2. AWS API Gateway: Amazon API Gateway is a fully managed service that makes it easy for developers to create, publish, maintain, monitor, and secure APIs at any scale.
3. AWS S3: AWS S3 is Object storage built to store and retrieve any amount of data from anywhere
4. AWS DynamoDB: Amazon
   DynamoDB is a fast and flexible nonrelational database service for
   all applications that need consistent, single-digit millisecond latency at any scale.
5. AWS Route53: For creating and registering a domain name for the web app.
6. AWS IAM: AWS IAM for creating users,roles and policies.
7. AWS Cognito: for authentication, access control to your web app.

Comment: Yeah. I was thinking about the same same services which you mentioned before. But, I may not be using the cognito services since this is the public application and doesn't require any authentication at this moment. Maybe would consider in future if the complexity of project increases.